# Replicating the same font used in iOS settings using Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

From what I can see the default font used in iOS is San Francisco.

[image]

I am creating a page of settings for my application and I would like to use this font. Can anyone tell me how I can access and be sure that my XF app is using this font With iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set custom fonts in Forms .

#### in iOS

Firstly , download the font file (San Francisco.ttf) and place in your Resources folder. Make sure the build type is BundleResource.

[image]

[image]

In addition to this, on iOS you have to open up your info.plist, and add in the file names of the fonts you want to use.

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
    <string>xxx.ttf</string>
</array>
```

###Using Custom Fonts

Now we get to actually using them. Because referencing fonts requires different syntax for each OS. To best accommodate this, in your Application Resources, it is good to define your fonts.

For iOS we take the exact name of the file, without the extension (without .ttf)

In Android , since we don't set the value , it will still display the default font .

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" x:Key="NormalFont">
        <On Platform="iOS" Value="xxx" />  //xxx is San Francisco.ttf file name without .ttf extension
    </OnPlatform>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then to use the font, you just need to reference the key.

```
<StackLayout>
    
    <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin Forms! (San Francisco in iOS)" FontFamily="{StaticResource NormalFont}" />
</StackLayout>
```

###Update

As the default font of UIControl in iOS is **Helvetica** . `San Francisco` is available after iOS 9.0 . So it is necessary to download it if your app need to support iOS 8.0 and before . After iOS 9.0 you don't need to set the font any more . `San Francisco` is the default font in iOS .

Comment: As SF is also a system font, is there not a way to access that directly without downloading a copy of it and adding to resources folder?

Comment: Hi Lucas,  So how can I specify the default font for iOS and another for example Roboto-Regular.ttf#Roboto-Regular for Android?

Comment: Check https://xamarinhelp.com/custom-fonts-xamarin-forms/ .

Comment: Why did you cancel accept the answer ?  They are different question , you could create a new thread with more details so that people can help you better .

Comment: Because if it's the case that it is the default font I think it's not good for people to be downloading a font as suggested with your answer.